# Convert edgelist file to adjacency matrix for ucinet

Tags: adjacency-matrix

I have a dataset in a notepad file. It's in a format of edgelist. I want to convert it into an adjacency matrix to import it in an ucinet software. I don't know how to do it? Could you help me?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: No Nothing.I dont know what to do?

Comment: and i don't know that ucinet can accept the form of edge-list as an entrance for analysis or not?